# Does StellaSDK or Apportable work on non game apps?

Tags: android, ios, apportable

All the examples I see for these "compile to android" projects are games that use a single XIB for the interface. Has anyone used one of these with a storyboard and an app with normal controls, and maybe the numeric keyboard for the iPhone and a custom keyboard for iPad, and segues and the like?

Comment: You should ask this on their forums respectively contact their support.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like more advanced apps are not supported.